# Android : Choose Intent to open from Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on android project. In my activity i have four buttons. The user has to select the particular button to receive the notifications. So the next time if i select Notifications(its a fragment of nav drawer) it should directly lead me to that particular activity instead of again selecting the department.

1st Run
Nav Drawer (select Notification)>>Opens Activity(to choose button to receive notification) >> Opens that particular activity

2nd Run

Nav Drawer(select Notification)>> Directly opens the selected activity

Notification.class

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mateoj.multiactivitydrawer.department.dept_1styeartab;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;

public class notifications extends BaseActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    Button clickButton;
    Button clickButton1;
    Button clickButton2;
    Button clickButton3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
        Pushbots.sharedInstance().setCustomHandler(customHandler.class);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("com.mateoj.multiactivitydrawer", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ncs);
        clickButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nmech);
        clickButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nece);
        clickButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.neee);




    clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent show = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), noti_cse.class);
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().tag("cse");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("mech");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("ece");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("eee");
                editor.putString("session", "cse").commit();
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(show);


            }
        });
        clickButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent show = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), noti_mech.class);

                Pushbots.sharedInstance().tag("mech");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("ece");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("eee");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("cse");
                editor.putString("session", "mech").commit();
                editor.commit();

                startActivity(show);


            }
        });
        clickButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent show = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), noti_ece.class);

                Pushbots.sharedInstance().tag("ece");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("mech");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("eee");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("cse");
                editor.putString("session", "ec").commit();
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(show);


            }
        });
        clickButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent show = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), noti_eee.class);

                Pushbots.sharedInstance().tag("eee");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("ece");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("mech");
                Pushbots.sharedInstance().untag("cse");
                editor.putString("session", "eee").commit();
                editor.commit();

                startActivity(show);


            }
        });


        onStartUp();





    }




    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        onStartUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        onStartUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        onStartUp();
    }

    private void onStartUp()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.mateoj.multiactivitydrawer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String str = sharedPreferences.getString("session", "");
        if (str.equals("cs")) {
            clickButton.setClickable(true);
            clickButton1.setClickable(false);
            clickButton2.setClickable(false);
            clickButton3.setClickable(false);

        } else if (str.equals("mech")) {


            clickButton.setClickable(false);
            clickButton1.setClickable(true);
            clickButton2.setClickable(false);
            clickButton3.setClickable(false);
        } else if (str.equals("ec")) {


            clickButton.setClickable(false);
            clickButton1.setClickable(false);
            clickButton2.setClickable(true);
            clickButton3.setClickable(false);
        } else if (str.equals("eee"))
        {

            clickButton.setClickable(false);
            clickButton1.setClickable(false);
            clickButton2.setClickable(false);
            clickButton3.setClickable(true);
        }

    }


















  /*  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }  */




    @Override
    protected boolean useDrawerToggle() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_credits)
            return true;

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            onBackPressed();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

The onStartup code saves the preferences

Comment: Why did you call onStartUp() from onStop, onPause, onDestroy???

Comment: it saves the preference if i don't exit the app properly